# Close other accordion elements in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, accordion

I've implemented my own accordion elements so I'm not using ui-bootstrap.

I'm trying to close other accordion when I click on another one.

I currently have an initialize function where I state that all the accordions are closed. When you click on one of the accordions it will activate the toggleActive function which toggles the clicked accordion. If you click when another accordion is still opened it's supposed to close. Only one accordion can be opened.

HTML

```
           <div class="job-item" ng-repeat="job in jobs">
                <div ng-init="init(job)" ng-click="toggleActive(job)" ng-class="{'job-heading-collapsed': job.active, 'job-heading-expanded': !job.active}">
                    <h3>{{ job.title }}</h3>
                    <span ng-class="'fa fa-chevron-' + job.direction"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="slideDown" ng-hide="job.active">
                    <div class="expand-collapse-content">
                        <p>{{ job.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp')
.controller('JobsCtrl', function($scope, jobsService){
    var jobs = jobsService.getJobs();

    jobs.then(function (data) {
        $scope.jobs = data.data;
    });

            $scope.init = function(job) {
                    job.active = true;
                    job.direction = "down";
            }

            $scope.toggleActive = function(job) {
                    job.active = !job.active;

                    if(job.active) {
                            job.direction = "down";
                    } else {
                            job.direction = "up";
                    }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the current job and change its state before changing the state of the new job clicked. Your toggleActive function is only changing the state of the new Job, not the job currently opened.

In your JobsCtrl, keep track of which job current.

```
var current =null;
```

In your Init, initialize current.

```
current = job;
```

In your toggleActive first change the state of current, then set it to the new job.

```
current.Active = !current.Active;
current = job;
```